# Auto indentation plugin for Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm looking for a plugin that can indent code (HTML, CSS, PHP, ASP, etc.) in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

In Visual Studio (and a few other Microsoft editors), you can auto format a document with a simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. This inserts line breaks and tabbing automatically.

Is there a similar feature in Notepad++?

**Requeriments**

- Work with Notepad++
- Windows 7+
- Must implement shortcut for it
- No too "heavy" (not more than Notepad++ itself)

**Optional**

- May have other features
- Able to define how to indent each language

---

I looked and couldn't find any "inbox" feature that covers it. I also gave a try using:

- [**Code alignment** for Notepad++](http://www.codealignment.com/ForNotepadPlusPlus.html). There are good tools in the Code Alignment, but not what I'm looking for. Below what I'm searching.
- **TextFX** didn't the job as I expected, maybe I didn't use as I should have?

  [image: Screenshof TextFX’s menu]

---

```
// Some examples using PHP, but I want it to be used in other languages like ASP as well as CSS and HTML
<?php
    public function x()
    {
        $foo = 'test';
            $bar = 1;
return $foobar;
    }
?>

<?php
    public function x()
    {
                $foo = 'test';
                $bar = 1;
                return $foobar;
    }
?>

// What I'm looking for
<?php
    public function x()
    {
        $foo = 'test';
        $bar = 1;
        return $foobar;
    }
?>
```

Comment: [Meta related](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/603/how-should-we-treat-questions-about-plugins)

Comment: You might wish to see [this answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/626/185), which mentions the appropriate plugins. Found by a [search for "notepad++ indent"](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=notepad%2B%2B+indent) (the only hit, btw).

Comment: You can highlight the lines and press tab to indent a big chunk at once. (And shift+tab to undo/remove) Is that not what you're looking for then?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Why don't you try the [**Indent By Fold**](https://www.fesevur.com/indentbyfold/) plugin?

[image: Screenshot of the menu 'Plugins' → 'Indent By Fold']

Here's your PHP code *indented by fold*:

[image: Screenshot of a PHP file before and after]

(The image above **is not assembled** from two separate images! Notepad++ has the ability to clone its tabs in a new view.)

You can access [a screencast demo](http://screencast.com/t/tUD2nfeLX) for the 'Indent By Fold' plugin. There's no separate plugin for the 'auto complete' feature in the video; for most languages there are defined already XML files with keywords:

[image: Screenshot of a XML file]

Now, about the 'Code Alignment' plugin: just use it only if you are not satisfied with the 'Indent By Fold' results!

---

Here's how you can define a shortcut for the the indent operation:

[image: Screenshot of the Shortcut Mapper]

The <kbd>Ctr + K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> shortcuts key are already "taken" (by 'comment code' and 'duplicate selection'), therefore I've choosed another combination. But everyone can re-map all the commands according to own needs.

---

If anytime you find a language with a "weak" 'code formatting / folding' you can take the lead, and proceed in defining your own folding and coloring rules for keywords, comments, numbers, operators and delimiters:

[image: Screenshot of 'Folder & Default' menu]

See how beautiful 'Indent By Fold' works when I press <kbd>ALt + K</kbd>?

The *vbproc* keyword is underlined because the 'DSpellChecker' plugin is active.

[Here are a large amount of UDLs](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/User_Defined_Language_Files) (User Defined Languages) for Notepad++. To better understand how to use this feature I recommend you to read the [UDL 2.0 online documentation](http://udl20.weebly.com/index.html). It was a time when folding was possible only for single words like "BeginSub" and "EndSub". Now it is easier because folding can be done using expressions, as you can see in my *My better ASP* example. Even now, the UDL cannot address every imaginable situations (there is a work in progress called UDL 3). But can we blame the Notepad++ developers for not achieving perfection with this free and simple, yet wonderful utility?

Comment: Amazing answer. Really complete. Thanks for the instruction as well, and the step by step (I needed that).

Comment: For those having trouble installing the "Indent By Fold" plugin, see here: http://deano.me/2013/07/indent-by-fold-for-notepad-not-installing-since-last-update/

Comment: Where exactly can I download it?

Comment: Just use the Plugin Manager. Also, you can download it from https://code.google.com/p/indentbyfold/

Comment: Indent By Fold can work wonders in many cases, but it won't work at all in some cases, e.g.: `<form><input><input><input><input><input></form>`

Answer (score 3):

Here are most of the plugins, to format your code.

- **JStool** (JSmin)
- **UniversalIndentGUI** (Enable 'text auto update' in plugin manager → UniversalIndentGUI, Shortkey = CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+J)
- **TextFX** (Shortkey = <kbd>CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+B</kbd> or TextFX > TextFX Html Tidy > Tidy: reindent XML; TextFX has the benefit of wrapping long lines, which XML Tools does not do, but doesn't indent those new lines correctly.)
- **XML Tools** (customized plugin for XML; Shortkey = <kbd>CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+B</kbd> or XML Tools > Pretty print [Text indent] . XML Tools complements TextFX by indenting the newly wrapped lines nicely.)

Comment: Updates on year 2020: 

  1. JStool use Ctrl - Alt - M combination. 
  - IndentByFold worked also, but was slightly worst for my case. 
  - UniversalIndentGUI was not found. 
  - Auto Detect Indentation - I didn't figure out how to get this to work.